# How to convert JSON to Java object if I do not know all json fields before parsing?

Tags: java, json

My service can receive several different jsons, such as:

```
{
   "event":"conversation_started",
   "context":"context information",
   "user":{
      "id":"01234567890A=",
      "name":"John McClane",
      "avatar":"http://avatar.example.com",
      "country":"UK",
      "language":"en",
      "api_version":1
   },
   "subscribed":false
}
```

or

```
 {
   "event":"message",
   "message":{
      "type":"text",
      "text":"a message to the service",
      "location":{
         "lat":12.34,
         "lon":12.34
      }
   }
}
```

or several else jsons. The only field that is the same for all jsons is "event". All other fields **can** be  different (depends on "event" value).

So the question is: how to convert those jsons to java objects (without making messy code)? The only way I know is to manually check "event" value (like `json.startsWith("{\n\"event\":\"message\"")` but I'm sure that there is any simple decision for doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways I've done this.  The first is to do what you're suggesting - parse the JSON, check the type, and create the object.  Be very careful with using a String parser as you may or may not have things like new lines.  Instead, do something like:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(eventString);
String eventType = jsonNode.get("event").asText();

if( eventType.equalsIgnoreCase("conversation_started")) {
    // create ConversationStarted object using something like:
    ConversationStarted conversationStarted = objectMapper.readValue( eventString, ConversationStarted.class );
}
```

This, of course, requires all classes to have a concrete POJO to allow for deserialization.

Another way is to do what many other programming languages do and have a key/value map.  There are a few ways to do this.  One is with the Jackson libraries:

```
Map<String, Object> map = objectMapper.readValue(eventString, new TypeReference<Map<String,Object>>(){});

Map<String, Object> user = (Map<String, Object>) map.get("user");

System.out.println( "conversation started - avatar is " + user.get("avatar"));
```

That way you can pass around the Map and extract as needed.  Note that you still need to understand the structure of the JSON but you don't need to have a POJO for it.

Lastly is a variation on the second solution.  Using [JSONPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) you can pull out what you need directly.  Again you will want to first check out which type of event you have.  Something like:

```
if( JsonPath.read(eventString, "$.event").equals("conversation_started") ) {
    String avatar = JsonPath.read(eventString, "$.user.avatar");
    System.out.println("conversation started - avatar is " + avatar);
 }
```

The last two methods require you to pull out values one at a time as shown.  The first solution gives you a full object to work with.  It is your call as to what works best in your environment.

Answer (score 0):

**UPD:** If you don't want to convert JSON String to JAVA Object via declaring a POJO, you can parse it to `JSONObject`(com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONObject)

```
public class Event {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jsonA = "{\"event\":\"conversation_started\",\"context\":\"context information\",\"user\":{\"id\":\"01234567890A=\",\"name\":\"John McClane\",\"avatar\":\"http://avatar.example.com\",\"country\":\"UK\",\"language\":\"en\",\"api_version\":1},\"subscribed\":false}";
        String jsonB = "{\"event\":\"message\",\"message\":{\"type\":\"text\",\"text\":\"a message to the service\",\"location\":{\"lat\":12.34,\"lon\":12.34}}}";

        JSONObject jsonObject = JSONObject.parseObject(jsonA);
        String event = jsonObject.getString("event");
        if (event.equals("message")) {
            //do what you want to do
            System.out.println("message event......");
        } else if ("conversation_started".equals(event)) {
            System.out.println("context information event......");
        }
    }
}
```

Declaring a class of `Event` as below, and then convert JSON String to a `Event` JAVA object.

```
@Data
public class Event {
    private String event;
    private String context;
    private User user;
    private boolean subscribed;
    private Message message;

    @Data
    public static class User {
        private String id;
        private String name;
        private String avatar;
        private String country;
        private String language;
        private int api_version;
    }

    @Data
    public static class Message {
        private String type;
        private String text;
        private Location location;

        @Data
        public static class Location {
            private double lat;
            private double lon;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jsonA = "{\"event\":\"conversation_started\",\"context\":\"context information\",\"user\":{\"id\":\"01234567890A=\",\"name\":\"John McClane\",\"avatar\":\"http://avatar.example.com\",\"country\":\"UK\",\"language\":\"en\",\"api_version\":1},\"subscribed\":false}";
        String jsonB = "{\"event\":\"message\",\"message\":{\"type\":\"text\",\"text\":\"a message to the service\",\"location\":{\"lat\":12.34,\"lon\":12.34}}}";

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            Event eventA = objectMapper.readValue(jsonA, new TypeReference<Event>() {
            });
            System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(eventA));

            Event eventB = objectMapper.readValue(jsonB, new TypeReference<Event>() {
            });
            System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(eventB));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a JSON object.  This is dynamic and can load any json.  Then you can reference the event field consistently

Example 1

```
 //import java.util.ArrayList;
 //import org.bson.Document;


 Document root = Document.parse("{ \"event\" : \"conversation_started\", \"context\" : \"context information\", \"user\" : { \"id\" : \"01234567890A=\", \"name\" : \"John McClane\", \"avatar\" : \"http://avatar.example.com\", \"country\" : \"UK\", \"language\" : \"en\", \"api_version\" : 1 }, \"subscribed\" : false }");

 System.out.println(((String)root.get("event")));
```

Example 2

```
 //import java.util.ArrayList;
 //import org.bson.Document;


 Document root = Document.parse("{ \"event\" : \"message\", \"message\" : { \"type\" : \"text\", \"text\" : \"a message to the service\", \"location\" : { \"lat\" : 12.34, \"lon\" : 12.34 } } }");

 System.out.println(((String)root.get("event")));
```